# SharePoint 2010 FARM migration - from one environment to other environment

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migration

For migrating the SharePoint 2010 FARM from one environment to other environment what the are

1. Pre Checks
2. Post Checks
3. High level steps ( Or supporting links )
4. Best practices

Performed Migrations from one version to other version within the environment but from one environment to other environment as i mean from one domain to other domain. Little curious about user mappings and other effected things.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to make sure

1. Make sure your current farm is healthy, if their is any issue pending try to resolve it. I mean Heatlh check of farm. right down the Farm configuration.
2. Create new Services account in the new domain.
3. Back up all the SQL Databases
4. Now Setting permission for new service accounts on SQL Servers and DB.
5. Now Shut down SharePoint related Services on the Server i.e Timer service, IIS, admin service
6. Change the server domain.
7. Now updates the accounts for the app pools, services and farm admin account.
8. you have to migrate the user from old domain to new domain.
9. test the farm

check this url: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sushrao/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another/

Also check this option: https://yagyashree.wordpress.com/moving-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-a-different-domain/

this is if you are using the same server in 2nd domain, but if you want to use new servers then things are much easy.

- create and configure new SharePoint farm on new domain
- backup and restore the content db from old farm to new farm
- migrate the user to new domain.
- test it